# How did $u$ become the subject of this formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm struggling to see how the following step was made:

> $y = \ln n^\alpha + \ln B + (1-\alpha )\ln N - (1-\alpha ) u\quad \iff $
>
> $ u = \ln N + \dfrac {\ln n^\alpha + \ln B - y}{1-\alpha} $

What steps were done in-between these two lines?

Comment: I am unsure if this is how one should phrase a question that they plan on answering themselves. "Please can you show me how this was done?" ???

Comment: I tried to delete this question, but I couldn't.

Comment: Well you could always rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2):

Take $(1-\alpha)u$ to the LHS and $y$ to the RHS:

$ (1-\alpha ) u = (1-\alpha ) \ln N + \ln n^\alpha + \ln B - y$

Divide by $1-\alpha$:

$u = \ln N + \dfrac {\ln n^\alpha + \ln B - y}{1-\alpha} $